# Como organizar as colunas numa tabela

Tags: html, html5

Há alguma forma de fazer colspan para metade de uma coluna?!

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td> ola </td>
    <td> ola </td>
    <td> ola </td>
    <td> ola </td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td> ola </td>
    <td> ola </td>
    <td> ola </td>
   </tr>
 </table
```

Gostava que as colunas da segunda linha ficassem a cobrir a linha toda e que todas as células tenham o mesmo comprimento!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como nesse exemplo, as 2 colunas superiores estao a cobrir a tabela toda e a separação está no meio...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso com `colspan` e definindo um `width` de acordo com a quantidade de colunas dividindo por 100%. Por exemplo: 3 colunas = 33.3%, 4 colunas = 25% e por aí vai...

**Exemplo de 2 linhas de 4 x 3 colunas:**

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td width="25%"> ola </td>
      <td width="25%" colspan="3"> ola </td>
      <td width="25%" colspan="2"> ola </td>
      <td width="25%"> ola </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td width="33.3%" colspan="2"> ola </td>
      <td width="33.3%" colspan="3"> ola </td>
      <td width="33.3%" colspan="2"> ola </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**3x2:**

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td width="33.3%"> ola </td>
      <td width="33.3%" colspan="3"> ola </td>
      <td width="33.3%"> ola </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td width="50%" colspan="3"> ola </td>
      <td width="50%" colspan="2"> ola </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**5x4:**

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td width="20%"> ola </td>
      <td width="20%" colspan="4"> ola </td>
      <td width="20%" colspan="3"> ola </td>
      <td width="20%" colspan="4"> ola </td>
      <td width="20%"> ola </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td width="25%" colspan="2"> ola </td>
      <td width="25%" colspan="5"> ola </td>
      <td width="25%" colspan="4"> ola </td>
      <td width="25%" colspan="2"> ola </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

A lógica é meio complicada, mas se baseia nos valores dos `colspan` somados e no número de colunas. Veja que na linha onde possui mais colunas, eu não especifico `colspan` na primeira e última, apenas nas do meio. A soma dos `colspan` + número de colunas sem `colspan` de cada linha devem ser iguais. No primeiro exemplo, veja que somando o valor de `colspan="3"` na primeira linha + 2 colunas sem `colspan`, dá 5. Na segunda linha também dá 5 somando os valores do `colspan`. Esses números sobem à medida que vai se adicionando mais colunas.

**Veja um outro exemplo com 5x3:**

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td width="20%"> ola </td>
      <td width="20%" colspan="4"> ola </td>
      <td width="20%" colspan="3"> ola </td>
      <td width="20%" colspan="4"> ola </td>
      <td width="20%"> ola </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td width="33.3%" colspan="3"> ola </td>
      <td width="33.3%" colspan="7"> ola </td>
      <td width="33.3%" colspan="3"> ola </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Veja que a lógica segue a mesma: somando os valores da primeira linha, 1+4+3+4+1 = 13. Na segunda linha também: 3+7+3 = 13.

Comment: era exactamente isso que eu pretendia, muito obrigado pela resposta, entendi perfeitamente

Answer (score 0):

Só usar colspan = numero total de colunas

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td> ola </td>
    <td> ola </td>
    <td> ola </td>
    <td> ola </td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4"> ola </td>
   </tr>
 </table
```

Comment: eu quero 4 elementos na primeira linha e 3 na segunda

Comment: editei a minha pergunta, talvez seja mais facil entender o que pretendo com a imagem

Comment: @Droopy na figura vejo 2 células na primeira, uma linha branca estreita no meio e uma linha com 3 células

Comment: exato, a linha branca não interessa, eu quero obter esse resultado quando uso 2 celulas numa linha e 3 noutra

Comment: por exemplo se eu meter 2 celulas numa linha e 3 noutra linha a linha que tem as 2 celulas vai ficar com um espaço vazio

Comment: @Droopy, não consegue, faz uma tabela com duas linhas, e em cada linha mete uma tabela. A primeira divide em 4 ou 2 células e a segunda divide em 3 células